# Discord Giveaway Bot with requirements

Tags: discord.py

I am new to discord.py and ive tried to make a giveaway bot with requirements that would be roles from the server yet no matter what i try it either lets you enter no matter what or stops you from entering and says the required roles were 'None','None','None' and im really confused why.

These are the parts i believe dont work:

```
@client.command()
async def gstart(ctx,time: str, prize: str, winnr: int,req :discord.Role,req2:discord.Role,req3:discord.Role):
 reqsplit = str(req),str(req2),str(req3)
 requ1 = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name = req)
 requ2 = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name = req2)
 requ3 = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name = req3)
 requs = str(requ1),str(requ2),str(requ3)
 reqstr = (f"{reqsplit}")
 role_list = []
 for i in reqsplit:
   role_list.append(discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=i[0:-1]))
```

The dictionary

```
 my_msg = await ctx.send(embed = gstart)

 await my_msg.add_reaction("")

 role_dict[my_msg.id] = requs,prize
```

And the reaction event

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
  message = await client.get_channel(payload.channel_id).fetch_message(payload.message_id)
  default_bypass_role = discord.utils.get(payload.member.guild.roles, name="<<1 Billion Donor>>")
  if all(x in role_dict[int(str(message)[12:30])][0] for x in payload.member.roles ) or payload.member == message.author or default_bypass_role in payload.member.roles:
    pass
  else:
    await message.remove_reaction('', payload.member)
    await discord.DMChannel.send(payload.member,f"Sorry you can't enter the Giveaway since you do not have the required role: `{role_dict[int(str(message)[12:30])][0:1]}`")
```

Please dont tell me my code is bad i already know that but i would appreciate any help as ive been stuck on this for ages.

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome the the wonderful world of happiness and sometimes frustration that is discord.py. First of all if you want multiple req maybe indefinite you can do this:

```
def foo(ctx,*,req : discord.Role):

  for role in req:
    ...
```

In that code what we do is say to python that every argument after context is req.

Second thing is a bit of a question... When you call the command do you pass the name of the role?
If yes then don't typehint to: discord.Role do it to str, later you get the role with the name so it won't matter in my point of view.

So I won't give you the direct solution but remember what I said before, with that you can do it yourself. That is what matters learning...

Good luck, and if you have any questions about what i said, leave a comment

Comment: ```async def gstart(ctx,time: str, prize: str, winnr: int,*,req :str):
  for role in req:
    reqsplit = req
    reqstr = (f"{reqsplit}")
    role_list = []
    discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles,name=req)
    for i in reqsplit:
      role_list.append((discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=i[0:-1])))```    if all(x in role_dict[int(str(message)[12:30])][0] for x in payload.member.roles ):
  File "main.py", line 234, in <genexpr>
    if all(x in role_dict[int(str(message)[12:30])][0] for x in payload.member.roles ):
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not Role

Comment: Thats the code and the error i get when trying to add what i think you mean